# Apply transformation matrix to meshgrid

Tags: matlab

For my application, I created a `meshgrid` of 3d-image coordinates.
Therefore, the code looks like:

```
Nx=50;
Ny=50;
Nz=100;

xgv=1:Nx;
ygv=1:Ny;
zgv=1:Nz;

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv);
```

In the next step, I want to recalculate the coordinates by adding a transformation matrix. I thought of transforming my `meshgrid` to a Nx3 point cloud, so I do this step:

```
 x=reshape(X, numel(X), 1);
 y=reshape(Y, numel(Z), 1);
 z=reshape(Y, numel(Z), 1);

points=[x,y,z];
```

And apply for example a rotation to them:

```
points_new = R*points';
```

For further steps, I need my 3d coordinates in `meshgrid`-format to use `interp3`.
So I thought of two possible solutions:

1. Is there a way to transform the new point cloud back to a meshgrid?
2. Is there a way to apply the transformation on the `meshgrid`-formated-data directly without any transforming to Nx3 point cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

1. Yes, you can use `reshape` after the transformation to make the shape the same as the inputs (more info below).
2. Technically yes, but not recommended. To do this you would have to multiply out the different terms of the rotation matrix which would ultimately result in more code and it would be harder to read.

Your approach is actually just fine. You *could* perform another `reshape` after the transformation to get the `meshgrid` shape back if you wanted.

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv);
original_size = size(X);

%// Then after transformation
Xnew = reshape(points_new(1,:), original_size);
Ynew = reshape(points_new(2,:), original_size);
Znew = reshape(points_new(3,:), original_size);
```

**But** the *shape* of the input coordinates to `interp3` doesn't actually matter (just the values) so you can leave them the way that they are after the transformation (as column vectors).

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv);

%// Create an N x 3 matrix of coordinates
points = [X(:), Y(:), Z(:)];

%// Transform the coordinates
points_new = points * R;

%// Use the result *directly* in interp3
interp3(data, points_new(:,1), points_new(:,2), points_new(:,3));
```

Comment: thanks for this great and short solution! It works fine!